# The extension of smooth function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

If $U$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ whose boundary is smooth, and $f$ is a smooth function on $U$ whose partial derivatives of all orders have a continuous extensions to $\bar U$. For an arbitrary domain $V \supseteq \bar U$, is there a smooth function $\tilde f$ on $V$ extending $f$?

Answer (score 3):

The case of a half space is a classical result of Seeley (Proc. AMS 15 (1964) 625-626), and your case should be just a corollary, using a suitable partition of unity and local change of variables near the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the Whitney's Expansion Theorem, whose condition is even weaker, that the domain $A$ of $f$ is merely required as a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the extended function is analytic.

See [Analytic Extensions of Differentiable Functions Defined in Closed Sets](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1934-036-01/S0002-9947-1934-1501735-3/S0002-9947-1934-1501735-3.pdf).